# Using the AKS http-addon returns a 503 for my service

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I have a service that I want to expose publicly over http running on AKS. I created a Kubernetes cluster and enabled the HTTP addon following these instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/http-application-routing). I then launched a service **myservicea** in namespace **mynamespace**. And then I created an ingress controller for using the following configuration.

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myservicea-ingress
  namespace: mynamespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: addon-http-application-routing
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myservicea.XXXXXXX.westus.aksapp.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myservicea
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

The domain `myservicea.XXXXXXX.westus.aksapp.io` is reachable after several minutes, however, I only get an HTTP 503 error. So the ingress controller does not seem to be able to find my service. What could be the issue?

Comment: well, can you verify your service works without ingress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you create the service in a specific namespace. Then maybe you can set the deployment and ingress also in that specific namespace. And you should check in the portal if the host route the request to right namespace. I did the test follow the link you posted with just changing the namespace and it works in my side. The screenshots here:

[image]
[image]

Hope this will be helpful. If you need more help please give me the message.

Comment: Thanks there were two issues. The ingress needed to be created in the same namespace as you said, and my backend server wasn't starting.

Comment: Oh, it seems I also need to be more carefully at the work. Thank you for reminding me.